# OneHotEncoder change name columns

Tags: python, label, categorical-data, one-hot-encoding

i use OneHotencoder for transform categorical column to numerical data but the algorithm change name of columns. how i save the same name columns ?

(I use python 3)

My Data-Frame like this :

```
>>> import pandas 
>>> import numpy
>>> ar = numpy.array([['yassine', 1], ['jack',7], ['ahmed',4]])
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame(ar, columns = ['name', 'label'])
>>> df
      name label
0  yassine     1
1     jack     7
2    ahmed     4


>>> import category_encoders as ce
>>> ohe = ce.OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore', 
    use_cat_names=True)
>>> label_fournisseur = ohe.fit_transform(list(df['name']))
>>> label_fournisseur
   0_yassine  0_jack  0_ahmed
0          1       0        0
1          0       1        0
2          0       0        1
```

I need the columns to stay the same without any change:

```
     yassine    jack    ahmed
0          1       0        0
1          0       1        0
2          0       0        1
```

thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can change the names of the columns as you see fit. To remove the "0_" you can do for example:

```
label_fournisseur.columns = [ x[2:] for x in label_fournisseur.columns ]
```

Another way to get what you want (without another library):

```
pandas.get_dummies(df["name"])
```

results in:

```
       ahmed  jack  yassine
0      0     0        1
1      0     1        0
2      1     0        0
```

Note: get_dummies does one hot encoding if input has one category per observation (your case). For other cases (multiple categories per observation) the whole question should be changed different (as you can't have one category only in the column name).

Comment: thank you @vladmihaisima, but each time the algorithm does another modification like 0_yassine_ or 0_0yassine. i dont understand why does that

Comment: Generally, you do not need the column names. If you want to retrieve the initial categories you use inverse_transform. It can help to have recognizable column names (for example for debug), and you can change them if you want, or use another library. I have edited the answer accordingly.